# How to inpect Async/Promise using Reflect.getMetadata

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, metadata, reflect

I found this bug when i'm testing https://github.com/ztytotoro/rxjs-extension/blob/master/src/decorators.ts#L20

```
export const AsyncFunction = async function () {}.constructor;

export function isAsyncOrPromise(fn: any): boolean {
  return fn instanceof Promise || fn instanceof AsyncFunction;
}
```

#### ⏯ Playground Link

**Playground Link:** [Provided](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.0-beta#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAGTgcwBRQIYCc0CmUAXItmAJ4A0iA1gRaQM5S4xhqIA+iTFAtgCM4AGxoATAkwhsADlDi5SABVxxZBXFAoARKTJjzFASlIA3ODHGIA3gChEiCAhaJtGxAF5EAJQLARAmgAOkIoAFkibHFsHAwAckkmGDQwYlwiEFwwdwJ4mhx8Ihp6CmMAbgcnF1ECYJF0DFKCig1g5zAWXBBoRWCwbH4CCrsAXzs7CBFsJiZEPX44WyqAAVQ0KpmKSF5sMwIMNMQwECFNU0RVOH4YJgIAHi72NAA+ZcdHDtcMphARKC8ZAA7tgYACrjc7sEfqJ9hgAAYAEhsYFGvB6EAIBHE8JGH0QGSgWSQPz+UEqjnG4y+AMki0BYAIQPmBEWGBGdi2O1AkFgCEQ-FBYHZKjUkIe5Aob3snxqgXqjXigvY+QFQvaLlYPQUuH6g2GFOqnQBpP+gOwILBiDpcGCTD2BwAjCNxnZlcKRkA)

#### Code

```
function Log(target: any, key: string | symbol, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor): void {
  const type = Reflect.getMetadata('design:returntype', target, key);
  console.log(key, type.constructor.name);
}

class Demo {
  @Log
  async save(n: number): Promise<string> {
    const result = await Promise.resolve(`${n} succeed`);
    return result;
  }
}
const demo = new Demo();

async function main(): Promise<any> {
  console.log('main', main.constructor.name);
  const result = await demo.save(1);
}

main();
```

#### Actual behavior

```
save Function
main AsyncFunction
```

#### Expected behavior

```
save AsyncFunction
main AsyncFunction
```

### Demo2

```
function Log(target: any, key: string | symbol, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor): void {
  const type = Reflect.getMetadata('design:returntype', target, key);
  console.log(key, type instanceof Promise);
}

class Demo {
  @Log
  async save(n: number): Promise<string> {
    const result = await Promise.resolve(`${n} succeed`);
    return result;
  }
}
const demo = new Demo();

async function main(): Promise<any> {
  const result = await demo.save(1);
}

main();
```

**Playground Link:** [Provided](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.0-beta#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAGTgcwBRQIYCc0CmUAXItmAJ4A0iA1gRaQM5S4xhqIA+iTFAtgCM4AGxoATAkwhsADlDi5SABVxxZBXFAoARKTJjzFASlIA3ODHGIA3gChEiCAhaJtGxAF5EAJQLARAmgAOkIoAFkibHFsHAwAckkmGDQwYlwiEFwwdwJ4mhx8Ihp6CmMAbgcnF1ECYJF0DFKCig92FnIIAjhgRFU4fhgmAgq7AF87OwgRbCYmRD1+OFsqgAFUNCrZikhebDMCDDTEMBAhTVM+tUHhgB4WNg4APhXHR2cwVwymEBEoLzIAHdsDB-v0bnVvqIDhgAAYAEhsYDGvBAEC6BHEsNGb0QGSgWSQ31+UEqjgmEw+rkkSwBYAIgIWBCWGFGdm2u1AkFgCEQ-BBYFZKmuQwIt3IFBe9neLn+xL+AOwwNBiBpcGCTH2hwAjKMJnZ+exWZUgA)

#### Actual behavior

```
save false
```

#### Expected behavior

```
save true
```

Answer (score 0):

was hard to find how to solve it - and I can't explain why it works

For Demo 1 I think this is the correct implementation:

```
function Log(target: any, key: string | symbol, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor): void {
  const type = Reflect.getMetadata('design:returntype', target, key);
  console.log(key, type.name); // 'Promise'
}

class Demo {
  @Log
  async save(n: number): Promise<string> {
    const result = await Promise.resolve(`${n} succeed`);
    return result;
  }
}
const demo = new Demo();

async function main(): Promise<any> {
  console.log('main', main.constructor.name); // 'AsyncFunction'
  const result = await demo.save(1);
}

main();
```

Demo 2 code

```js
function Log(target: any, key: string | symbol, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor): void {
  const type = Reflect.getMetadata('design:returntype', target, key);
  console.log(key, type === Promise); // true
}

class Demo {
  @Log
  async save(n: number): Promise<string> {
    const result = await Promise.resolve(`${n} succeed`);
    return result;
  }
}
const demo = new Demo();

async function main(): Promise<any> {
  const result = await demo.save(1);
}

main();
```